# Cannot properly edit and save worker node specs in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeadm, kubectl, minikube

I have a Kubernetes cluster setup using KubeAdm (Setup in EC2 instances in AWS Cloud). The CNI used is Flannel and the cluster is running quite well. My requirement is that I am trying to setup **KubeVirt** (https://kubevirt.io/) in my Cluster to provision VMs along with pods in my cluster. KubeVirt is an open-source sandbox project from CNCF. I have setup KubeVirt and it's running fine. I followed the steps in this link to setup KubeVirt: https://kubevirt.io/quickstart_cloud/

After that, I wanted to spin up a VM in my Kubernetes cluster. So, I followed the official documentation from: https://kubevirt.io/labs/kubernetes/lab1.html

The VM got created, but was in a '**scheduling**' phase. I observed that along with the VM, an associated pod also got created in the cluster.The issue is that this particular pod is not getting scheduled and is in pending state.

[image]

After describing the pod, I got the following error messages which says something about a device plugin:

[image]

> Warning  FailedScheduling  2m5s (x4 over 22m)     default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient devices.kubevirt.io/kvm. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.

There are no taints in my worker node, however this pod won't get scheduled. Then I found a link which was mentioning about the Device plugin of KubeVirt (https://kubevirt.io/2018/KVM-Using-Device-Plugins.html).

Looking at the Worker node description, under '**allocatable**->**devices.kubevirt.io/kvm**' it's mentioned as "**110**" and when I edited my worker node, it was "**0**"

[image]

I tried to edit the worker node and change the value to "110". I saved the change and it displayed `node/kube-c2-workernode-02-poc edited`.

However, after I edit it one more time, the previously added change was totally gone as if I didn't modify it at all. I tried to increase the worker node specs by increasing the CPU cores, memory and IOPS in the EBS volume. But effortlessly, the result is still same.

**So, after going through the merry-go-round and coming down to the issue, how do I make changes to resource allocation of a worker node in Kubernetes and properly save it?**

Comment: Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubevirt requires virtualization to be enabled.

Those "allocatable" / "capacity" is not something that you can/should not change yourself. They just reflect the state of your node: you can not host virtual machines here, thus your virt-launcher Pod is stuck Pending.

Currently, the only way to have this in EC2 is to use metal instances.

On bare-metal, in general: we should make sure virtualization instructions are enabled at the BIOS level (VT-x / AMD-v). At which point, your node would register that virtual machines can be scheduled.

Comment: So in short, this cant be performed in ordinary EC2 instances or EKS/AKS? Is that what we have arrived at?

Comment: Hey it worked! I changed the instance type of both master and worker node to 'm5.metal' and it automatically worked. "Kubevirt requires nested virtualization to be enabled." - Think this is what was missing in the setup. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: and actually: "nested virtualization instructions" is what you would need to enable on the hypervisor, running a Kubernetes node that needs to run its own virtual machines. From the Kubernetes node perspective: you just need virtualization instructions, ... my mistake / edited my answer